# Serverless Framework - Share code between multiple services

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

I have multiple services

```
root/
    services/
        subscriptions/
        users/
    shared/
        httpUtils.js
        database.js
    node_modules/
    package.json
```

When I'm running severless locally using serverless-offline my imports work without a problem:

```
const _ = import('lodash') // module_modules
const database = require('../../shared/database')

However, when I deploy the application won't start because of
error: cannot find module lodash
error: cannot find module ../../shared/database
```

Does each service need to have its own node_modules dependencies within the service? It would be great if I could just load dependencies from a single node_modules at the root and the shared folder.

What's the standard practice in order to accomplish this for a project with multiple services?

- each services gets its own copy of the shared files and node_modules?
- private npm package with shared libs?
- another packaging tool?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended that you use a packages.json for each service rather than try to use a single one shared across multiple services. You can get additional details about the use of package.json and the serverless framework [here](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/share-code-between-services.html).

I have tried various techniques to share a single node_modules directory, but the solutions are fragile and eventually something will go wrong as I introduce more dependencies and start to version the services.

I do try to share as much as possible across my services, but have determined it isn't worth the effort to share a single node_modules directory.